# How to connect to 30 awg Nichrome wire to 28 awg wire?

Tags: wire, wire-terminals

I'm looking for a quick way to connect my 30 awg Nichrome wire to some 28 awg stranded wire and have tried an inline splice and crimped-on receptacles.

For my project I'll potentially be making lots of these joints and want to make sure I've looked at all my design options. The length of the Nichrome wire is some what critical, and so far the crimped connections make the length a little easier to control.

Are there any other ways to do this that would be better or make the results more repeatable?

Answer (score 1):

Is this for a high temp situation where solder might melt? What was suboptimal for your crimp?  Reliability?

You could spot weld them like a thermocouple.
 http://www.sunstonespotwelders.com/spot-welder-200ws-single-pulse.php might handle wires that small.  Another options might be simple screw terminals.

Comment: I couldn't find any butt splicers that would work for 30 awg and didn't cost a fortune. So I ended up crimping on a receptacle and attaching to a header. This turned out to be too many steps since I might be doing a bunch of them. Temp should only get to 100C. Screw terminals will most likely be too bulky for my application.